# Inserting images using Flask-FlastPages

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-flatpages

I have created my blog using Flask-FlatPages and the posts are in Markdown, the challenge I'm having is inserting images in my blog post. The traditional way of inserting images in markdown  is not working.

I also tried this without success:

```
![image]({{ url_for('static', filename="img/my_image.jpg") }})
```

Comment: So what error are you getting? What does it look like... does it just not work? Can you insert any other image without templating?

Comment: @PatrickAllen, it just does not work, all that is rendering on the html page is the place holder with the Alt text.  I can't insert images in any other way, because the problem is happening during the markdown to html conversion process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mix images with Markdown in a Flask app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576520/mix-images-with-markdown-in-a-flask-app)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick fix! let's say we have a images folder, and we want to use the `images/flower.jpg`

**Step 1**: Put the `images` folder in the `static` folder.

**Step 2**: In the text, link the image with `../static/images/flower.jpg`.

for example:

```
![flower](../static/images/flower.jpg)
```

or

```
<img src="../static/images/flower.jpg" alt="flower">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me. It turns out that FLATPAGES_HTML_RENDERER is needed to achieve this goal.

Here is the code:

```
def my_renderer(text):
    prerendered_body = render_template_string(text)
    return pygmented_markdown(prerendered_body)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['FLATPAGES_HTML_RENDERER'] = my_renderer
pages = FlatPages(app)
```

This is also discussed on this post:
https://github.com/SimonSapin/Flask-FlatPages/pull/1

Answer (score -1):

There are nothing wrong during the markdown to html conversion process.

I think it because bleach.clean() function.

You can try to add  to allowed_tags.

```
allowed_tags = ['img']
allowed_attrs = {'img':['src','alt']};
target.body_html = bleach.linkify(bleach.clean(markdown(value,output_format='html'),tags=allowed_tags,attributes=allowed_attrs,strip=True));
```