# How should I markdown an img in Flask-Markdown?

Tags: flask

I developed a basic markdown text editor for my website.
My issue is that after I make a link to an image in my static/img file, it does not seem to want to markdown that.

I have a textarea where I can do headers, like so:

## Hello

formatting such as bold like so,

**hello**

(These both work)

but my images do not render, per the markdown docs like so:

Does anyone have markdown working with an image with flask-markdown. My guess would be that it does not want to have a url_for('static'..) behind the scenes, but I could be wrong.

Seems Flask-Markdown has not been updated since 2013 (not a good sign).

Edit: 
cat image note lack of exclamation mark, makes it a link to a route.

-- Couple other similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576520/mix-images-with-markdown-in-a-flask-app)

Answer (score 0):

Answer was found on another SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30835901/inserting-images-using-flask-flastpages/47532359#47532359). The solution is to use the relative path. I feel pretty silly for looking at url_for for something so simple